# Buscar úsuario com @ na frente - query builder/eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

estou criando um sistema de marcação de úsuarios e gostaram de saber como eu faço para buscar um dado exatamente como está escrito, por exemplo:

fulado de tal @teste

gostaria de buscar somenteos registros que tem extamente o @teste, eu estou fazendo assim no momento:

```
$username = '%@' . $username . '%';
$this->whereRaw('conteudo LIKE ? OR localizacao LIKE ? ', [$username, $username])
```

só que desta forma ele busca que tem algo parecido com $username e não somente o $username, eu tentei retirar os '%', mas dessa forma trouxe um objeto vazio, desde ja agradeço a todos!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

`$username = '%@' . $username . '%'; $this->where('conteudo', $username)->orWhere('localizacao', $username)`

Você pode tentar utilizar o where e o orWhere para fazer esta busca porque o Like sempre vai buscar "algo parecido" como você citou ai.

Poderia fazer o teste para ver se resolve seu problema.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).